# Data Loaded: <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message

Tags: php, database, google-maps

I have searched for solutions but nothing seems to be working. I have added the port 3307 (web africa) south africa.but I still get this error

> Data Loaded: 
>  **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed
>   out' in /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11 Stack trace:
>   0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', NULL, NULL) 1 {main}
>   thrown in **/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php** on
>   line **11**

My code looks like this

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");// database connections
// Get parameters from URL
$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lng = $_GET["lng"];
$name = $_GET["name"];
$time = $_GET["time"];
$description = $_GET["description"];
$sighting = $_GET["sighting"];
//Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.spri.co.za;port=3307;dbname=kruger_park_live",$sean_sql,$########);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    // Prepare INSERT statement new sigting
        $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_maps (ID, map_client_name, client_time, client_lat, client_lng, client_description, client_sighting)  VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        // Assign parameters
        $stmt3->bindParam(1,$name);
        $stmt3->bindParam(2,$time);
        $stmt3->bindParam(3,$lat);
        $stmt3->bindParam(4,$lng);
        $stmt3->bindParam(5,$description);
        $stmt3->bindParam(6,$sighting);
        $stmt3->execute();
        $data[] = array("name"=>$name, "lat"=>round($lat,6), "lng"=>round($lng,6),"time"=>$time,"description"=>$description,"sighting"=>$sighting);
        //Data for success
        echo json_encode($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error Message.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", phpsqlinfo_addrow.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
}
//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

and the dbinfo.php like this

```
<?php
 $host= "****;port=3307"; $username="****"; $password="****"; $database="****"; $dbname="****";


?>
```

Comment: Probably want to remove your password from that

Comment: Just so you know, you're displaying unsanitized user input when you json_decode those raw values.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=...;dbname=...,$s..,$P..);
      // I removed the actual values for your security
```

but your variables are

```
$host= ""; 
$username="..."; 
$password="...";
$database="...";
```

I believe you want to do

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);
```

you set your variable, but were using the values as the variable names

this is apparent when looking at this line in the error message -

```
PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', NULL, NULL)
                                       ^^^^  ^^^^
```

Comment: okay I changed it to: $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.*;dbname=*",$S,$P); and the db info.php to  $host= "*;port=3307"; $database="*"; $dbname="*";$username="S"; $password="P"; but i am getting; <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '*' (110)' in /home/sea503/publi /phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', NULL, NULL)
#1 {main} thrown in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />

Comment: sorry for being an pain in the ass I have just been struggling with this for a week now

Comment: You are still not using your variables correctlly -`;__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', NULL, NULL)` if you are doing   `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.*;dbname=*",$S,$P);` you are still not using your `dbinfo.php` variables correctly. You need to do `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);`. where `$host`, `$database`,`$username`,and `$password` are spelled the EXACT same as they are in `dbinfo.php`

Comment: also did you change `dbinfo.php` to `$host= ";port=3307"; $database=""; $dbname="";$username="S"; $password="P";`? You need to change them back to what you first posted. I just used `...` in my example because I did not want to keep your username/password visible.

Comment: okay I have them all exactly the same: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.spri.co.za;dbname=kruger_park_live',$s,$P); in the dbinfo I have: $host= 'mysql.spri.co.za;$dbname=kruger_park_live';$username='s'; $password='P'; I am getting the same error though should I tell it what table to use as well? Or am I missing an obvious mistake here

Comment: if what you posted here is your code you still have it wrong - `$s` != `$username` and `$P` != `$password`. You need to do `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database',$username,$password);` and in your `dbinfo.php` - `$host= "mysql.spri.co.za;port=3307"; $database="kruger_park_live"; $username="Sean_sql"; $password="Paaseiers01";` I tried not to repost your actual username/password, but it does not look like you are understanding. Let me know when you correct this and I will delete this comment so your username/password are not visible.

Comment: again `$sean_sql` is not the same as `$username` and `$Paaseiers01‌` is not the same as `$password`!!! change `$sean_sql` to `$username` and `$Paaseiers01‌` to `$password`. You cannot create a variable (`$username='sean_sql'`) and then change the name of it to the value (`$sean_sql`). That is not how php variables work. Do EXACTLY this - `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database',$username,$password); and in your dbinfo.php - $host= "mysql.spri.co.za;port=3307"; $database="kruger_park_live"; $username="Sean_sql"; $password="Paaseiers01";`

Comment: as an alternative, since you don't understand how php variables work, you can just put your information directly in the PDO object - `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.spri.co.za;port=3307;dbname=kruger_park_live',"Sean_sql","Paaseiers01");`

Comment: copied it like you said. now it is is giving me the following; Data Loaded: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '$host' (25)' in /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php(11): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=$hos...', 'sean_sql', 'Paaseiers01')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br /> I take it the problem lies on the server side

Comment: sorry it was late last night when I was doing this and I missed an something obvious. Since `mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database` was in single quotes `$host` and `$database` are not being parsed. Try again with double quotes `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);` OR directly with `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.spri.co.za;port=3307;dbname=kruger_park_live',"Sean_sql","‌​Paaseiers01");`

Answer (score 0):

I have made `""` to single `''`

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=myhost;port=xxxx;dbname=db_name",$sean_sql,$########);
```

to

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;port=xxxx;dbname=db_name','$username','$password');
```